# Can I restrict a test for a nested enum using SFINAE to a class without base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

When I use SFINAE to detect at compile time if a class has a type, then this seems to include also derived types. Ideally I would like to test for the existence of an enum, but it shows the same effect: Both tests work in general, but they also return true if the class derives the type or enum.

[Live example here!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=12079e81ac0703969e191af46784a845-db5fabe6cf5813f7944baf25744e32d9)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { enum { IsTagged }; struct IsTaggedStruct{}; };
struct B :A {};
struct C {};

template< int > struct HasTag;

template< class TST >
struct Check
{
    template< class T2 > static char (&Test( ... ))[1];
    template< class T2 > static char (&Test( HasTag<T2::IsTagged>* ))[2];
    //template< class T2 > static char (&Test( typename T2::IsTaggedStruct* ))[2];
    static const bool value = sizeof(Test<TST>(0))==sizeof(char[2]);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Value A=" << Check< A >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value B=" << Check< B >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value C=" << Check< C >::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
+ g++ -std=c++03 main.cpp
+ ./a.out
Value A=1
Value B=1
Value C=0
```

Wanted output is only A=1, rest 0. Only one test for enum or type is enabled at a time, of course. GCC with C++03.

**tl;dr:** With SFINAE a test if a type exists in a class is also true for derived classes, how to restrict to the very class?